# Why should an Angular controller instance be published into a scope property?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In recent 1.2.x angular versions (maybe also older) controllers can be initialized using expression as

```
<div ng-controller="demoController as vm"></div>
```

The documentation explains this as:

> The controller instance can be published into a scope property by
>   specifying as propertyName.

http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.4/docs/api/ng.directive:ngController

In which scenarios does this help?

Comment: It also says: _"Notice that the scope becomes the `this` for the controller's instance. This allows for easy access to the view data from the controller"_

Comment: I'm guessing this is so if you know what you're doing you can access the internal variables set by the ngModelController.

Comment: like alias in MySql you can just cut off long name and use short one

Comment: Here's some discussion: http://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-experimental-controller-as-syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The controller is instantiated with `new`, so it's a prototypical object. Meaning it can have prototype methods. However the methods are called from the view as unbound methods with "this" set to the scope. This largely defeats the purpose of it being a prototypical object, since "this" inside the methods can't reach the object instance.

There's actually been some back and forth on this... Angular pre-1.0 used "this" as the controller instance, I forget exactly how that worked, maybe the controller instance and scope were one and the same. With Angular 1.2+ it's a bit of a return to that style, to treat the controller functions more as constructors than as merely collections of functions.

In this new 1.2 style, you only ever add one thing to the scope (the controller instance) and reference all the data off of that. This has the benefit of working with controllers that are in a "class like" constructor form with prototype methods, and conveniently defeats the common gotcha of writing to an ng-model that's in a scope more inner than your realized. The workaround for that is including a dot somewhere in your lvalue expression.

Answer (score 0):

Using the controller as syntax has a few advantages:

- If you're using a language like `typescript` or `coffeescript` then you can easily use a class for your controller:

  ```
  //TypeScript example
  class MyCtrl {
      name: string = "";

      constructor(private $log) {
          $log.info("Initializing MyCtrl");
      }

      doSomething() {
          this.name = "foo"
      }
  }
  ```

  sample view

  ```
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl as ctrl"> 
      <span ng-click="ctrl.doSomething()">{{ctrl.name}}</span>
  </div>
  ```

  And even if your not using `coffeescript` or `typescript` you can do the same thing with prototypes....it just looks a bit uglier.
- If you have multiple controllers in a view then using the "controller as" syntax will ensure that you don't have any naming conflicts
- For beginners to angular using $scope can be confusing

Comment: Just because I am curious: When do I get a naming conflict if I don't initialize a controller via an expression?

Comment: If two controllers both have a field named "foo" and you are using both controllers in the same view then you can't uniquely specify which "foo" you are refering to. e.g.: 
<div ng-controller="ctrl1"> <div ng-controller="ctrl2"> Who's foo is this: {{foo}} </div> </div>

Comment: Yes, resolving naming conflicts makes sense, especially when having nested controllers scenarios where we have something like scope.foo and child-scope.foo. Using the 'as' insures you reference the expected target.